# some european CDNs?

Tags: cdn

someone knows some CDN providers in Europe?

cause i keep seeing big names like amazon, google, akamai, simplecdn, yahoo in all google searches.

does it even matter where the CDN providers are located? cause apparently it won't matter cause their network grid is world wide:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last sentence is correct. You need to look at where their points of presence are, not where the company itself is located.